# Illustrator: Prevent stroke crossing with converging shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I've got three triangular shapes, converging towards a single points. Even though I've chosen inline stroke alignment, the strokes cross at the converging anchor point (see picture). How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make the stroke->cap & corner-> round cap & round join. Then, if you don´t like rounded corners, you can cover them with a simple triangle.
But there is another problem in that shape. The 3 green shapes don´t match. So you need to go in:

apparence-> and grab the stroke to put before the fill. This will adjust the weird online stroke.

Comment: Hi and thanks, but the stroke already appears before the fill in all shapes :/

Comment: It should be after the fill, sorry. You must grab it down...This image could help you          http://i.imgur.com/w3XWl0l.png

Answer (score -1):

u can try expand for your object
after that u can edit her points

Comment: Hi Nur Hafidz. Welcome to GDSE and thanks for contributing. Could you expand your answer a bit to include _how_ to do this and _why_ this would work. We aim more at educating users than at telling them what buttons to click. Thanks and keep contributing!